# PL SQL Update working in one window but when I try to fetch the record back it hasn't changed

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

So in PLSQL Developer:

```
   UPDATE someTable t
   SET animals      = 'hamsters'
   WHERE t.someIdentifier = 'XXXX';
SELECT * 
FROM someTable t  
WHERE t.someIdentifer = 'XXXX';
```

appears to work as the select query in the final line does indeed confirm that animals has been set to equal the value 'hamsters'.

However, when I run the select query on it's own,

```
select * from someTable t  WHERE t.someIdentifier = 'XXXX';
```

animals doesn't seem to have updated. Any general pointers as to where this problem might be coming from would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you forget `commit` update? Try to add commit below the update:

```
UPDATE someTable t
SET animals      = 'hamsters'
WHERE t.someIdentifier = 'XXXX';
commit;
```

There is one more **not recommended** option, but it's good to know:

```
SET autocommit ON
```

Comment: IMO `SET autocommit ON` is such a bad advice ... throw the transaction management out of the window instead of understanding how it works :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Yes, I don't recommend this option too, but it is one more solution ;). I removed it.

Comment: well, you could include it but I think it should come with a big warning sign :) Especially since in the long run it will create more problems than it solves !

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit the update transaction first

```
UPDATE someTable t
SET animals      = 'hamsters'
WHERE t.someIdentifier = 'XXXX';

commit;
SELECT * 
FROM someTable t  
WHERE t.someIdentifer = 'XXXX';
```